# Python RE "Sub" Method. Pyschools T12 Q13

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm struggling with regular expressions this exercise asks using RE to write a code that replaces any double vowels from a string in to a single vowel. So far I can replace one vowel at a time but not all of the vowels here's the problem along with my script.

*Fill in the RE below so that the resulting string will remove double vowel with single vowel.*

```py
import re
regex = r"(aa|ee|ii|oo|uu)"
repl = r"o" 

print(re.sub(regex, repl, 'pyschools'))
print(re.sub(regex, repl, 'steep'))
```

Comment: replace `([aeiouAEIOU]){2}` with `\1`?

Comment: that worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found this interesting. By doing:

```py
import re
regex = r"([aeiouAEIOU]){2}"
repl = r"\1"
```

You will be changing words like `psychoels` (two vowels but different) for `psychols` as well (not sure if it's intendeed).

If you expect to replace only equal double vowels (aa, ee, ii, oo or uu), i'd suggest doing something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#text-munging):

```py
import re
regex = r"(a{2}|e{2}|i{2}|o{2}|u{2})"

def repl(m):
  return m.group(1)[0]


print(re.sub(regex, repl, 'pyschoels'))
print(re.sub(regex, repl, 'steep'))
print(re.sub(regex, repl, 'stp'))
```

More on regex [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)